# Type Mismatch doing a Find+Replace in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Fairly new to PowerPoint VBA - I was under the impression that this was the boilerplate code for doing a basic Find & Replace throughout the slideshow (in this case the first 5 slides). However, I'm getting a `Run-time error 13 - Type mismatch` on line `For Each shp In sld.Shapes` and I can't figure out why. Any insight?

```
Dim sld As Slide, shp As Shape, i As Long

For i = 1 To 5
    Set sld = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes '<- Error here
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "LastMonth", "September")
                End If
            End If
        Next shp
Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Excel `Shape` is not the same as a Powerpoint `Shape`: you need to qualify your Declaration with the PowerPoint library.

```
Dim shp as PowerPoint.Shape
```

Comment: Talk about frusturating... I should've known... Switched and fixed, thanks

Comment: @dwirony with RD when you select that `shp` variable it says `Excel.Shape (class)` in the RD toolbar =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm trying to convince my IT guy to allow it on my work computer :)